# Mongo DB Query Syntax

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have the following row inserts into a Mongo DB table.

I need to get a query that does the following
a) Increases the number of caps for the players of Italian Teams only by 10%
b) Find all the players over 30 that contain the String "es"

Any help greatly appreciated.

db.teams.insert({

```
team_id: "eng1",
date_founded: new Date("Oct 04, 1896"),
 league: "Premier League",
 points: 62,
 name: "Manchester United",
 players: [ { p_id: "Rooney", goal: 85, caps: 125, age: 28 },
          { p_id: "Scholes", goal: 15, caps: 225, age: 28 },
          { p_id: "Giggs", goal: 45, caps: 359, age: 38 } ]
 });
```

db.teams.insert({

```
team_id: "spa1",
date_founded: new Date("Oct 04, 1912"),
 league: "La Liga",
 points: 80,
 name: "Barcelona",
 players: [ { p_id: "Messi", goal: 195, caps: 189, age: 30 },
          { p_id: "Valdes", goal: 0, caps: 158, age: 27 },
          { p_id: "Iniesta", goal: 72, caps: 25, age: 31},
          { p_id: "Pique", goal: 9, caps: 201, age: 38 } ]
 });
```

db.teams.insert({

```
team_id: "ita3",
date_founded: new Date("Oct 04, 1911"),
 league: "Serie A",
 points: 62,
 name: "AC Milan",
 players: [ { p_id: "Inzaghi", goal: 115, caps: 189, age: 35 },
          { p_id: "Abbiati", goal: 0, caps: 84, age: 24 },
          { p_id: "Van Basten", goal: 123, caps: 104, age: 35 } ]
 });
```

db.teams.insert({

```
team_id: "ita4",
date_founded: new Date("Oct 04, 1902"),
 league: "Serie A",
 points: 71,
 name: "Inter Milan",
 players: [ { p_id: "Handanovic", goal: 0, caps: 51, age: 29 },
          { p_id: "Cambiasso", goal: 35, caps: 176, age: 35 },
          { p_id: "Palacio", goal: 78, caps: 75, age: 31 } ]
 });
```

Comment: Could you post some code you have tried? Without it your question sounds like you are asking us to write the code for you. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a "write the code for me" site.

Comment: Hi Andriy,I am new to Mongo DB syntax and am getting a lot of errors when trying to do searches and updates that would be the norm in SQL. It can be difficult to find examples online as MongoDB has limited examples and I didnt really think error messages I am getting as a result of the syntax being incorrect would be helpful.